# How can I create a macro in Objective C to execute many modules in runtime?

Tags: ios, variables, module, runtime

In this source code is a link for module FirstDetailViewController

```
FirstDetailViewController *newDetailViewController = [[FirstDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstDetailView" bundle:nil];
detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
```

I want that a string

```
module = [[NSString] alloc] initWithString:@"SecondDetailViewController"];
```

I want to convert string module to code up for alter in runtime

```
module *newDetailViewController = [[module alloc] initWithNibName:module bundle:nil];
detailViewController = newDetailViewController;
```

where module is many names

```
module = [[NSString] alloc] initWithString:@"ClientDetailViewController"];
…;
module = [[NSString] alloc] initWithString:@"FriendDetailViewController"];
…;
module = [[NSString] alloc] initWithString:@"FishDetailViewController"];
…;
```

How can I use variable module to implement this?

Comment: Just as a note. `module` cannot be used for both the class name and the nib name since they are different in your example...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UIViewController* newDetailViewController = [[NSClassFromString(module) alloc] initWithNibName:module bundle:nil];
```